# Angular 4/5 + Spring Boot + Oauth2 support

Tags: spring, angular, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

i have my web app builded with Angular 4/5 and Spring Boot. Now i want to add user-accounts to my app and there i have some problems. I would like have my Auth serwer (in Spring Boot) and also i want use providers like Facebook and Google. There is my first question, when user will choose Facebook to auth, then how my resource server will know who is asking for resource. When i use my own Auth serwer i am doing it like this:

```
@GetMapping("/user/name")
public ResponseEntity<String>(Principle principle) {
     return new ResponseEntity<String>(principle.getName(), HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

and this is working, but how to get user username when user is using Facebook or Google auth?

**My second questions** is how to properly handle expire Tokens time in Angular 4.

**My third and last questions.** Some resources from my server will be availible for
not logged user(annonymous) so how can i protect my resources to prevent other's than my clients using my API?

If you have some advices or examples, please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't worry about the rude comment on your question, Single Sign-On (SSO) can be pretty complicated.

If your using Facebook and Google as optional SSO providers then what you have to realize is that those providers are going to give you some sort of unique identifier along side the user information when you request it.

Spring Security and the corresponding Spring Boot auto configuration has some pretty good support for linking SSO user information to a Principal. Ill add some good references below to help understand Springs solution for this. I'm going to assume Spring Boot 2 and Spring Security 5 since your versions aren't listed.

- [Spring Boot 2 OAuth2.0 Client Configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-security-oauth2-client)
- [Spring Security 5 Custom OIDC User Service](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.0.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#oauth2login-advanced-oidc-user-service)
- [[VIDEO] Next Generation OAuth Support with Spring Security 5.0 - Joe Grandja](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WhrOCurxFWU)

You can also look into [Spring Social](https://projects.spring.io/spring-social/) if your looking to do more than just SSO.